# setting values with vanila js in dom element value is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

[image]here is a website https://secure.givelively.org/donate/lifesteps
I want to type custom values here with simple js/jquery
It doesn't work when  we click on continue

i tried

```
document.querySelector("#custom-input-element").click()
```

and

```
 document.querySelector("#custom-input-element").focus()
```

and

```
document.querySelector("#custom-input-element").value='1';
```

all of them not worked

Comment: hello @Andy there is a custom input field just after 250$

Comment: last one is working if we write and execute this statement in console

Comment: hey @decpk it works but when we submit it shows please select the value and also if it proceeds we have 25 $ default selected value in next page

Comment: see the attached screenshot @Andy

Comment: Ha. I use uMatrix to prevent JS scripts from loading (a little ironic I suppose). When I allow them access I can see the form. That information might be useful to you though: you would have to wait for those scripts to load and update the DOM before your script could work.

Comment: yeah I waited and tried but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let elem = document.getElementById("custom-input-element");  
const prevVal = elem.value;
elem.value = 1;//Your Value
elem._valueTracker.setValue(prevVal);
let event = new Event("input", { target: elem, bubbles: true });
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
$('#custom-input-element').click(() => console.log(clicked));
```

i just used this on my machine to make sure it works, or make sure the html id is not misspelled